# How to connect a java application to db2 database on another computer?

Tags: db2

I want to connect my java application to a db2 database on other computer on same network.

what will I need to do for setting up database on remote computer. what will url be like for JDBC driver ?

Answer (score -2):

first, you must add the db2 jdbc driver to the classpath of your java application.

Once, it's done you choose your library to connect to database : you have the choice to use default java.sql library or to use a framework like hibernate, ibatis ..etc. the url for DB2 is like `jdbc:db2:hostname:port/databaseName`
 for example : `jdbc:db2:db2host:50000/yourdb`

You can pick the driver for your needs here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

Here is a sample code to connect:

```
public class Connect {

 public static void main(String[] av) {
String dbURL = "jdbc:db2:db2host:50000/yourdb";
try {
  // Load the jdbc-odbc bridge driver
  Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");

  // Enable logging
  DriverManager.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter((System.err)));

  System.out.println("Getting Connection");
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "yourdbuser", "itspassword"); 


  SQLWarning warn = conn.getWarnings();
  while (warn != null) {
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + warn.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("Message:  " + warn.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Vendor:   " + warn.getErrorCode());
    System.out.println("");
    warn = warn.getNextWarning();
  }

  // Do something with the connection here...

  conn.close(); // All done with that DB connection

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("Can't load driver " + e);
} catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println("Database access failed " + e);
 }
  }
}
```

Comment: will this method work if database is on other computer than the application ? Is there a way to use ip address instead of hostname ?

Comment: sure you can use the ip address instead of the hostname

Comment: do I need to install db2 on the system that is running java application ?

Comment: No you should only download the DB2 jdbc driver from the link in my response and it to the project dependencies if you use a dependency manager like maven ant gradle or add it simply to the classpath of your java application

Comment: and what is required at server side ? I have installed db2 Express C and have created the database to be connected with my java application. but Java application is unable to connect

Comment: on the db2 server there is nothin to do. Just add the driver  and use the code in the answer

Comment: getting this error : Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server /172.22.28.196 on port 50,000 with message: Operation timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: what is the port configured for your db2 server ?

Comment: 50000....i can connect to the same database if I run the application on the same computer .

Comment: from the the machine of your java application could you do a telnet on your db2 machine on port 50000 to see if it's not a problem of connection rights

Comment: may be there is a firewall or connection right problem that should be fixed. see with the sys/network admin

Comment: Your URL is wrong and it does not match the "app" driver that you are trying to use. The "app" driver is deprecated; you should use the JCC driver instead.

Comment: @mustaccio I have tried that too but it's not working.